# Xpages Dependent Dojo Filtering Select fields not working

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

In my Xpages form I have two fields where the user will select values from a @DBLookup. They are categories and subcategories.

I got this working using combo boxes, but then I discovered Dojo Filtering Select! This is an awesome control and perfect for what I need to do as the user wants to use type ahead and just tab when they get the value they want.

The fields work fine EXCEPT I cannot get the 2nd field to populate. It is dependent on the value of the first field.

My code is below:

```
    <xp:td>
                    <xp:label id="label3" value="Work Category" style="font-weight:bold"></xp:label>
                </xp:td>
                <xp:td>




                    <xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect2"
                        rendered="true" value="#{document1.workCategory}">
                        <xe:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[""]]></xe:this.defaultValue>
                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var db = new Array(@DbName()[0], 'TSCTT.nsf'); 
    @DbColumn(db, "workCategoryView", 1)
    }]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="complete">
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onBlur" submit="true" refreshMode="complete"></xp:eventHandler>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onFocus" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="complete">
                        </xp:eventHandler></xe:djFilteringSelect></xp:td>
                <xp:td>
                    <xp:message id="message3" for="workCategory"></xp:message>
                </xp:td>
            </xp:tr>
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td>
                    <xp:label value="Work Sub Category"
                        id="workSubCategory_Label1" for="workSubCategory1" style="font-weight:bold">
                    </xp:label>
                </xp:td>
                <xp:td>


                    <xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect3"
                        rendered="true" value="#{document1.workSubCategory}">
                        <xe:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[""]]></xe:this.defaultValue>
                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var db:NotesDatabase = session.getCurrentDatabase();
    var key:String = document1.getItemValueString("djFilteringSelect2");
    @DbLookup(db,"(DBLookupWorkSubCategoryView)",key,2,"[FAILSILENT]");

    }]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
                    </xe:djFilteringSelect></xp:td>
                <td></td>
            </xp:tr>
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the wrong field name (djFilteringSelect2 instead of workCategory).

Also, I will suggest you do a partial refresh instead of a full.

I don't think you need onBlur and onFocus events. Just use the onChange event.

**Update**

This example works:

```
<xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect2" value="#{document1.workCategory}">
    <xe:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[""]]></xe:this.defaultValue>
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                @DbColumn("", "workCategoryView", 1)
        }]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="djFilteringSelect3"></xp:eventHandler>
</xe:djFilteringSelect>

<xp:br></xp:br>

<xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect3" value="#{document1.workSubCategory}">
    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="required" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var key:String = document1.getValue("workCategory");
            @DbLookup("","(DBLookupWorkSubCategoryView)",key,2,"[FAILSILENT]");
            }]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xe:djFilteringSelect>
```

Notice how I have changed from reading the value from the 1st filtering select as document1.getItemValueString() to document1.getValue().

Also notice that I have added a dojoAttribute to tell the 2nd filtering select that it's not required because the required behaviour of the control caused the onchange partial refresh to fail and not run. If the filtering select is required, you can instead add an extra select item as the default value (as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22149104/785061)).

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't work ? An error occurs or onChange is not called when selecting value with keyboard in typeahead list ?

Have you seen my answer to your previous question about this ?
[Xpages Dependent Field Lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552169/xpages-dependent-field-lookups/23554631#23554631)

Replacing comboBox by djFilteringSelect should work

Comment: Even when I made the correction suggested by Mr. Lausten it still doesn't work. What I mean by that is that the second djFilteringSelect never has any possible values in it. This second field depends on the value the user selected in the first field. I cannot tell if the change event fires or not.

Comment: with Chrome, you can see if AJAX request is post to server when you select a value in first field ... or with a print in onChange event